# Easiest way to read/write a file's content in Python

Tags: python

In Ruby you can read from a file using `s = File.read(filename)`. The shortest and clearest I know in Python is

```
with open(filename) as f:
    s = f.read()
```

Is there any other way to do it that makes it even shorter (preferably one line) and more readable?

Note: initially I phrased the question as "doing this in a single line of code". As pointed by S.Lott, shorter doesn't necessary mean more readable. So I rephrased my question just to make clear what I meant. I think the Ruby code is better and more readable not necessarily because it's one line versus two (though that matters as well), but also because it's a class method as opposed to an instance method, which poses no question about who closes the file, how to make sure it gets closed even if an exception is raised, etc. As pointed in the answers below, you can rely on the GC to close your file (thus making this a one-liner), but that makes the code worse even though it's shorter. Not only by being unportable, but by making it unclear.

Comment: Create your own function. Then you can use it to get the contents. The call would be one line.

Comment: @Felix Hehe, sure. I was looking for a way to do it using the standard library. :)

Comment: Just curious, does the Ruby statement close the file as well?

Comment: Requirements state "read a file".  The end state of the file is not specified.  Leaving the file in any particular state (eg: "closed") is not required.

Comment: My example uses the *with* statement, which closes the file. I was looking for something equivalent. Deterministically closing the file is required.

Comment: @S.Lott Well, if you compare the Ruby code and any Python solution mentioned so far, Ruby wins for this one.

Comment: @ionut bizau: How is "shorter" a "win"?  It seems like "shorter" and "more confusing" would be a problem, not a victory.  After 30 years of looking at other people's code, code golf is just cost and complexity with no benefit.

Comment: I didn't say shorter was better. I just said that that particular piece of Ruby code was more readable than the Python equivalent. Being short is part of it. Being a class method rather than an instance method is another part. When you see the instance method being used in Python you immediately start thinking about who closes the file, what if there is an exception, etc. Ruby makes it clear - there is no instance involved. Sorry for being unclear. I'm rephrasing the question.

Comment: -1: "but also because it's a class method as opposed to an instance method"  What?  How is that advantageous.  Use `file()` instead of `open()`. "which poses no question about who closes the file"?  How so?  Where is that specified?  "how to make sure it gets closed even if an exception is raised, etc."  Where is *that* specified?  How is any of that more clear in the Ruby code?  What part of the Ruby says all of that?

Comment: How's file() different from open()? It's the same thing. They both return a "file-like object" which you have to deal with, and eventually get rid of when you're done. Having either a single library function or a class method to do all operations (open, read, close) implies you don't have to worry about close yourself. :)

Comment: @ionut bizau: `file` is the class-level constructor for files in Python.  Why do you like class-level methods in Ruby, but not in Python?  "implies you don't have to worry about close yourself"?  Really?  Why?  I don't get why the "Ruby makes it clear" (in one comment) or "implies" this (in another comment).  Your question doesn't make much sense -- unless you're simply arguing that Python's not good and Ruby is good.

Comment: My question makes sense for me. I'm trying to find a better way to write these two lines (4 lines before the `with` statement in 2.5). Maybe there is a way, maybe there isn't. I can always try to find out, right? If you don't like it, downvote and move on. :)

Comment: "My question makes sense for me."  Good.  It makes no sense to me.  You're simply saying that "The Ruby class method" approach is magically better because it allows you to play one-line code golf because it "implies you don't have to worry about close yourself".  Implies.  Unless someone is a Ruby expert, implies is a costly mistake.  Python says "Explicit is better than Implicit."  Yet, you're saying Implicit is better.  It sure sounds argumentative.

Comment: The benefit of `File.readlines("filename")` is that it reads the contents of a file given its name.  There is no file handle, descriptor, or object anywhere in evidence.  All the Python "equivalents" I've seen include an explicit open/close (or worse, an implicit open that requires an explicit close).

Comment: The docstring of `file` includes:  `The preferred way
to open a file is with the builtin open() function.`

Comment: `file(filename).read()`!

Comment: I edited this to use `open` instead of `file` because it's the more standard way, clearer to most python programmers and better shows the discussion but I'm not sure if it doesn't make some of the comments confusing.  If anyone's offended please feel free to edit it back. I won't attempt to re-revert.

Answer (score 197):

A one-liner.  No reason to do this.

```
with open('x.py') as f: s = f.read()
```

Answer (score 77):

Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text).

Python 3.5 and above:

```
from pathlib import Path
contents = Path(file_path).read_text()
```

For lower versions of Python use [pathlib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2):

```
$ pip install pathlib2
```

Then

```
from pathlib2 import Path
contents = Path(file_path).read_text()
```

Writing is just as easy:

```
Path(file_path).write_text('my text')
```

Comment: When I use pathlib, I get this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 148: character maps to <undefined>`.
And as far as I search, it seems I can't set encoding to pathlib, so I have to read the content traditionally with the os module.

Comment: Note that the `pathlib2` backport is worthless on Windows with python 2.7 as it does not support non-ascii chars on this platform - see [known issues](https://github.com/jazzband/pathlib2?tab=readme-ov-file#known-issues).

Answer (score 42):

This is same as above but does not handle errors:

```
s = open(filename, 'r').read()
```

Comment: Not really, yours leaves the file open.

Comment: The CPython implementation does close the file when the reference count goes to zero, but that is an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: This does handle errors; an exception will be thrown as usual.  This does *not* "leave the file open", but what it may do is cause the file close to be *delayed* depending on the GC implementation.  That can be a problem (locking in Windows, and eg. FD limits if looping over many files), but that's very different from leaving the file open (eg. leaking the file).

Comment: @Glenn Maynard:  Theoretically closing can be delayed until termination of the process, and in the meantime, the open file could leak (for instance to subprocesses in case of a `fork()`).

Comment: There are lots of ways that can happen; for example, objects keeping an sqlite db open; a PRNG module keeping /dev/urandom open, and so on.  It's a very good idea to close files explicitly, and there are issues like these to keep in mind if you don't, but a GC-delayed close isn't a leak.

Comment: It is portable enough for the scope of "I want it one line long" without requiring overengineering lessons ("you can port your oneliner to Jython")

Comment: My goal is not using a one-liner, that's why I would never accept this solution, even though it's probably fine in most cases on most implementations. It's just confusing, for me and for others.

Comment: No, this isn't confusing in the slightest.

Answer (score 20):

```
contents = open(filename).read()
```

Comment: And when do you close the file?

Comment: @ionut bizau - When the return of `open(...)` is garbage collected, I think. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't Perl; you don't want to force-fit multiple lines worth of code onto a single line.  Write a function, then calling the function takes one line of code.

```
def read_file(fn):
    """
    >>> import os
    >>> fn = "/tmp/testfile.%i" % os.getpid()
    >>> open(fn, "w+").write("testing")
    >>> read_file(fn)
    'testing'
    >>> os.unlink(fn)
    >>> read_file("/nonexistant")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/nonexistant'
    """
    with open(fn) as f:
        return f.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple like that:

```
    f=open('myfile.txt')
    s=f.read()
    f.close()
```

And do whatever you want with the content **"s"**

Answer (score 4):

Slow, ugly, platform-specific... but one-liner ;-)

```
import subprocess

contents = subprocess.Popen('cat %s' % filename, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaargh! (excess 'a's to meet min char limit)

Comment: Certainly matches the spirit of the question... perverse use of Python to make it resemble Bash is no worse than making it resemble Ruby or Perl.