# Python: How do I output all the text contents of a directory containing .txt files as a list?

Tags: python, list, nlp, glob

I have a directory file containing three thousand .txt files which contain scraped text paragraphs.

I'm trying to output a list in python in which each list row contains the contents of one of the .txt files

I'm very new to python and all I've managed to get to so far is;

```
import glob

mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("/Users/Downloads/Datasets/transcripts/*.txt")]
```

However, all I get from this is a list of 3,000 with each row containing the title of the .txt file and not the contents

Was wondering if anyone could help out, thanks :)

Comment: Hint: [Read a file's content in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758147/easiest-way-to-read-write-a-files-content-in-python).

Comment: @MillyCodsworth: Does the answer given solve your problem? Then you are supposed to accept it by clicking the check/tick next to it. (I just saw that you have made two requests, but haven't accepted any answer, so I thought I'd tell you. I was about to answer your other answer on splitting strings in SQL by the way, which you deleted right before I could post my answer, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 1):

The `glob` method returns a list of file *names* (or paths).  You need iterate over that list, opening the files and appending the contents to your list as you go:

```
texts = []

for text_file in glob.glob("/Users/Downloads/Datasets/transcripts/*.txt"):
    with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
        t = f.read()
        texts.append(t)
```