# convert .txt file to image

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have txt be like this " 01100000,10101000,01101000,01110000,10101100,01110000,01101000  "
how can I read this file to use it in this code ?

```
value = " how can read file here"
vdiv = [value[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(value), 8)]

def diff(inp):
    if inp == '1':
        return (0,0,0)
    if inp == '0':
        return (255,255,255)
    else:
        pass

img = Image.new( 'RGB', (8,len(vdiv)), "white")
pixels = img.load()

##
for x in range(img.size[0]):
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        for i in vdiv:
            for i2 in i:
                pixels[x,y] = diff(i2) #Creates a black image. What do?

img.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to read/write a file's content in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758147/easiest-way-to-read-write-a-files-content-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `open('filename.txt', 'r').read()` like so:

```py
fd = open('filename.txt', 'r')
value = fd.read()
fd.close()

...
```

Comment: I have this error " pixels[x,y] = diff(i2) #Creates a black image. What do?
TypeError: color must be int or tuple"

Comment: @kayla that would be a separate question